# How to run this C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation

I am learning C++ using C++ Primer 5th edition. In an exercise, I need to use auto that is in C++. The source code is given below. When I try to compile that using this:

```
g++ stringlength.cpp -o stringlength.exe
```

it does not work and doesn't correctly recognize `auto`.
But when I compile it using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 stringlength.cpp -o stringlength.exe
```

it shows a whole list of errors I have not seen. 
Please tell me what should I do to successfully compile this code.

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1, str2;
    cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
    getline(cin, str1);
    cout << "Enter another sentence: " << endl;
    getline(cin, str2);
    auto size1 = str1.size();
    auto size2 = str2.size();
    if (size1 == str2)
    {
        cout << "The strings \"" << str1 << "\" & \"" << str2 << "\" are of same length." << endl;
    }
    else if (size1 > size2)
    {
        cout << "The string \"" << str1 << "\" is longer than \"" << str2 << "\"" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "The string \"" << str2 << "\" is greater than \"" << str1 << "\"" << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

A fragment of the error the second time:

```
s.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from stringlength.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:214:5: note: template
<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&
, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:214:5: note:   templa
te argument deduction/substitution failed:
stringlength.cpp:15:15: note:   mismatched types 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>' and
 'unsigned int'
  if (size1 == str2)
               ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algoba
se.h:67:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\char_trait
s.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from stringlength.cpp:1:
```

Comment: I had to down-vote this question: You should read your own code carefully before asking a question. Your problem was caused by a simple typo - that does not warrant a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need the `-std=c++11` option because auto with the meaning you use has been added in C++11. So the second command line is ok. The errors you see are caused by the line

```
if (size1 == str2)
```

I guess you meant

```
if (size1 == size2)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you compile with the `-std=c++11` flag, you are doing so correctly, because your using the newer C++ revision that supports the `auto` keyword.
When you compile with this flag, you are getting compile errors - which is completely normal. It's telling you that there is an issue with your code:

Your comparing a string with an unsigned int, this is evident from the line:

```
 mismatched types 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>' and unsigned int'
```

The variable `size1` has been defined implicitly, but its an `unsigned int`.
If your beginning C++ and programming in general, I would recommend you don't use the `auto` keyword (which assigns things implicitly rather than explicitly) , this is so you know exactly what type you are assigning and will make life a little easier to both read and debug:

```
string str1, str2;

// ....

unsigned int size1 = str1.size();
unsigned int size2 = str2.size();
if (size1 == str2)
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Now, you can immediately see that your attempting to compare `str2` which is of type `string` and `size1` which is of type `unsigned int`, which you obviously cannot do.

Comment: Thank You very much. I should have double checked the code. And the huge error list gave me horrors! That was just a little typo!
By the way, do you know some by which I can sort of, "alias" the -std=c++11 tag in windows cmd.

Comment: Like in a linux terminal? You could use doskey. Although i personally use bash scripts (windows you can use batch)